# Show shadow on AppCompatEditText

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

everyone. I have an AppCompatEditText field that is inside a TextInputLayout tag. Now I put a light shadow around the text box. Unfortunately, the whole thing is not displayed as I would like it to be, see picture. The lower part of the field does not appear. Do I have to set a distance, if so where?

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/suche"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="288dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="20dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="20dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="20dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgMain"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText

        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white_real"
        android:background="@drawable/search_for"
        android:hint="Suche..."
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"> 
 </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Your problem is that, by default, a `View`'s shadow is clipped to its parent's bounds. One possible solution is to disable that behavior by setting the `EditText`'s ancestors' `clipChildren` attributes/properties to `false`, but aside from the `TextInputLayout` itself, we don't really know what other `ViewGroup`s it might be nested inside internally, so we'd have to handle it in code to allow us to walk up the hierarchy; e.g., https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EA9Vy79XoCwW5C2TKLQgeOB06lsXZNtI/view?usp=share_link. Looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni25I.png. This is mildly hacky, IMO…

Comment: …and it would be more appropriate to have the `TextInputLayout` cast the shadow instead of the `EditText`, but that's gonna be a bit more cumbersome, and I'm not sure how you mean for the given background to factor into this ultimately. Also, as it is, I think the floating hint is going to overlap the shadow, which won't have a cutout for it, so that might not be want you end up wanting anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
```

Comment: `10dp` would be sufficient for showing/revealing shadow, but on the screenshot there is no shadow/space at all, so this `10dp` or `50dp` margin doesn't matter, isn't respected anyway... why? who knows, OP pasted only small snippet and we don't know anything about rest of layout and how it is placed. Personally I would blind-blame `layout_constraintTop_toTopOf` (or any `app:layout_constraint`-prefixed attr)

Comment: Yes, he needs to share whole layout instead of snippet